# how to disable label space into bottomNavigationBar in Flutter

Tags: flutter

Am trying to customize bottomNavigationBar. My intention is to remove label occupation spaces, including margin and padding. I want to center content horizontally and Vertically into this space.

My code:

```
bottomNavigationBar: Container(
            child: ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),
            bottomRight: Radius.circular(30.0),
          ),
          child: BottomNavigationBar(
            items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.pause,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  size: 40,
                ),
                label: '',
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Text(
                  "Imagine . Ariana Grande",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 13,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                  ),
                ),
                label: '',
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.arrow_circle_up,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  size: 35,
                ),
                label: '',
              ),
            ],
            //currentIndex: ,
            selectedItemColor: Colors.white,
            //onTap: ,
            backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
          ),
```

Result:
[image: This is my present result]

I want this:
[image: I want bottom bar like in this image below]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BottomNavigationBar has properties `showUnselectedLabels` and `showSelectedLabels`, set them to false.

[Flutter Docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html)

Comment: Its work very well with these attributes. Thanks

Comment: If you want to securely and truly eliminate the space below the BottomNavigationBarItem widgets, combine this with A.K.J.94's answer

Answer (score 8):

It can be solved by a property in BottomNavigationBar  `selectedFontSize: 0`

Comment: this is the ideal solution as it will remove the label's height also, not only hiding the labels

Comment: in addition, set unselectedFontSize: 0